# Finding the optimal line wrapping width in order to maximize the number of vertical same-value neighbors

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, algorithm, graphics

I have a `BitArray` of Length `n`. I can generate an Image by plotting the values on a bitmap (using the SetPixel method). The ending image is similar to a QR code. For now I wrap the sequence at `sqrt(n)`, so I have a square.  I want to determine the optimal folding/wrapping value `F` for which the number of same-coloured (1pixel wide) columns (`N`), and their height (`L`) are maximized.

[image: An example of what i said.]

I have no idea on how to implement this, for now.

Comment: I am unclear on the question.  Are you looking to maximize how often 2 pixels of the same color are together?  Are you looking to create the largest same-color rectangle that you can?

Comment: Is simply trying all combinations an option, or is `n` too large?

Comment: n is 22222 i think it would take a while but it could be much bigger...
The rectangle idea is cool

Comment: When you want to maximize the number (`N`) as well as the length (`L`) of those same-colored columns, you need to decide on a mathematical equation to maximize. Do you want to maximize `N*L` (area), or only `N` or `L`?

Comment: I think the priority is to be given to the height of the columns (`L`)

Comment: You said "same-coloured" pixels but marked only black ones in the example image. Do columns of white pixels count, too?

Comment: Yes they can be interchangable, as long as columns are made.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply autocorrelation to your sequence and find dominating periods (if exist). Then use periods corresponding to some largest peaks as wrapping value and check for the best result.

http://tisba.de/2012/02/21/how-to-find-periodic-effects-on-performance-using-autocorrelation/

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm just tries every possible folding value and determines the longest run of same-value bits. Its runtime is the worst possible, but still polynomial. I don't know how to make a faster algorithm without further constraining your problem.
*Code not tested!*

```vb
maxlen = 0  ' <-- what you called L
w_for_maxlen = 0  ' <-- what you called F

for w = 1 to n
    for x = 0 to w-1
        h = n \ w
        if x < (n mod w) then
            h += 1
        end if
        len = 0
        prev = False
        for y = 0 to h-1
            if bitArray[w*y + x] <> prev then
                len = 0
                prev = Not prev
            end if
            len += 1
            if len > maxlen then
                maxlen = len
                w_for_maxlen = w
            end if
        next y
    next i
next w
```